# Highcharts producing bizarre stroke seemingly at random on pie chart labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm modifying the font on the chart labels but there seems to be a stroke applied to some of the labels and not to others.

I have broken the chart down to a very minimal version and the stroke is still there. What is causing the stroke to show up and how can it be turned off for all labels?

```
$(function () {

Highcharts.theme = {
    colors:  [
  '#94B8D2',
  '#2a71a5',
  '#A699B9',
  '#4D3474',
  '#CDAED1',
  '#82368C',
  '#AAAEB2',
  '#565E65',
  '#EF92A5',
  '#DF264C',
  '#FFBA9D',
  '#FF763B',
  '#95FEDB',
  '#27CAE1',
  '#EAEAA1',
  '#D5D644',
  ]
};

// Apply the theme
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

    var donutData = [
      ['K01',6243],
      ['K05',1788],
      ['K07',8745],
      ['K08',16018],
      ['K12',11647],
      ['K18',0],
      ['K22',4482],
      ['K23',5166],
      ['K24',2922],
      ['K25',2103],
      ['K99',8410],  
    ];

    Highcharts.chart('StrokeProblem', {
        title: {
            text: "Bizarre Label Strokes",
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',           
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Stroke',
            innerSize: '75%',
            data: donutData,
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                        style: { fontSize: '17px' },
                    formatter: function(label){
                      label.color = this.color;
                            return this.point.name;
                    },
                }
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Here is the relevant [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u59176h4/39/).

Comment: did u mean the outline on the font? it seems to be present on all labels but with different color

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this is some default visibility property. Seems the darker fonts have a white stroke (not visible on white background) and the lighter fonts have a dark background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts automatically adds a text shadow to labels with a light font color. You can disable it with the textOutline property:

```
dataLabels: {
 style: {
  fontSize: '17px',
  textOutline: false
 },
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying `stroke` and looking for `stroke` in their documents finding nothing.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct. :)